# Filtering in google-drive-api not possible using createdDate

Tags: google-drive-api

My app has to retrieve files from google drive using file.list with q parameter. I would like to retrieve files between two dates out of thousands of stored data files.

It is not possible to filter using file.list q argument based on "created date" of the file.

As a workaround I used the "modifiedDate" for filtering. As long as the file is not modified every thing works fine since modifiedDate= createdDate.

In case the file is changed in any way or the file is shared with some other user the "modifiedDate" is changed, my app doesn't retrieve the files correctly anymore.

To retrieve all the files using file.list and filter them regarding createdDate later locally takes half a minute for retrieval from google drive.

Is there any viable workaround to get the files with creationDate between two dates?
In case there is not, could you add this possibility in google drive file.list q parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to do that currently with the drive api and not possible with the older deprecated api either ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/ )